# Неправильно работает ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Я пытаюсь реализовать ViewPager с 3 фрагментами. Когда переключаю между 1 и 3 фрагментом, 1 иногда пропадает. Как можно это исправить?

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{MyApplication.getInstance().getResources()
        .getString(R.string.popular_tab), MyApplication.getInstance().getResources()
        .getString(R.string.latest_tab), MyApplication.getInstance().getResources()
        .getString(R.string.category_tab)};

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return PopularFragment.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return LatestFragment.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return CategoryFragment.newInstance();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это поведение `ViewPager` по умолчанию: хранить текущий фрагмент, предыдущий и следующий. В вашем случае на фрагменте 3 фрагмент 1 удаляется.

Попробуйте добавить `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` - должно помочь.